# How to print output from algorithm into an input box on another program?

Tags: java

I am writing an algorithm to calculate something, is there anyway to get Java to then paste that string into the input box of another application e.g. Chrome
Currently have all the code, just no idea how to get the result out of terminal automatically, and be inputted into a focused input box.
Many thanks.

Comment: You could look into using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) for this. Selenium is a browser automation tool.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!